# Android : Gradient on relativelayout at bottom of screen

Tags: android, layout, gradient, shapes

I would like to put a gradient on the bottom layout, but it seems to work only with the top layout.

Here is the code of the main layout (test.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#FFF">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_height="60sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/tool_bar_gradient"></RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_height="60sp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/tool_bar_gradient"></RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code of the gradient (tool_bar_gradient) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:startColor="#257aa1" android:endColor="#6fb7d9" android:angle="90" android:bottom="450sp">
    </gradient>
</shape>
```

The result : the gradient is effective on the top bar, but not on the bottom bar...

What is wrong ?

PS : The target is Android 2.1-update1 or Android 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting this

[screen i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ9U5.png)

is anything that you didn't get it

Comment: You are right, it works at runtime, but not in the IDE....
There is a bug ine the IDE so !
Thanks for the time spent ;)